# Javascript Overlay on multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm running into some issues with an overlay I created in Javascript. I made a page with three teammembers. Whenever you hover over the teammember an overlay shows with a LinkedIn image and their name, which link to their LinkedIn profile.

What I want to achieve is that whenever I hover over teammember 1, only teammember 1 gets an overlay. What happens now is that whenever I hover over any of the teammembers the overlay shows over all three teammembers, instead of over a single teammember.

Any help is highly appreciated!

The script for the overlay is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // wanneer ik over .photo hover start de functie
    $('.person_up').hover(function() {
        // geef overlay weer
        $('.overlay').show();
        // animeer .overlay naar bottom: 0 en stop wanneer hover event verdwijnt (voorkomt dat het event afgemaakt moet worden)
        $('.overlay').stop().animate({bottom: '0'});

    },
    // als hover weg is dan deze functie
    function() {
        // .overlay weer op z'n oude plek
        $('.overlay').stop().animate({bottom: '-340'});
    });
});
```

The code on my page is:

```
<div id="team-images">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="team_person_wrapper">
                    <div class="person_up">
                        <img src="person1.jpg" alt="name person 1"></img>
                        <div class="overlay">   <a href="person1.html" target="_blank">
        <img src="Linkedin.png" alt="linkedin icon">
    <h3>Person 1 </h3>     </a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="team_person_wrapper">
                    <div class="person_up">
                        <img src="person2.jpg" alt="name person 2"></img>
                        <div class="overlay">   <a href="person2.html" target="_blank">
        <img src="Linkedin.png" alt="linkedin icon">
    <h3>Person 2 </h3> </a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="team_person_wrapper">
                    <div class="person_up">
                        <img src="person3.jpg" alt="name person 3"></img>
                        <div class="overlay">   <a href="person3.html" target="_blank">
        <img src="Linkedin.png" alt="linkedin icon">
    <h3>Person 3 </h3> </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/p3ejbgk5/)**

Comment: I've added a demo to your question. Please update it with your CSS so we can see the overlay, then update the URL in your question.

Comment: Thanks for this isherwood! I'm new to this so that's why I didn't make a jsfiddle in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // wanneer ik over .photo hover start de functie
    $('.person_up').hover(function() {
        // geef overlay weer
        $(this).find( "div" ).show();
        // animeer .overlay naar bottom: 0 en stop wanneer hover event verdwijnt (voorkomt dat het event afgemaakt moet worden)
        $(this).find( "div" ).stop().animate({bottom: '0'});
    },
    // als hover weg is dan deze functie
    function() {
        // .overlay weer op z'n oude plek
        $(this).find( "div" ).stop().animate({bottom: '-340'});
    });
});
```

You can try using `this` and a `find` to get the element u want...